# jquery if else button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi everyone i have a issue with jquery :

in my code i have two multiple selection one on the left one on the right and a button near the selection on the right and i when a click on it the text from the right is copiedinto an input this is already done.i can add or remove element from a list to another with two button :
add and remove . hope i have been clear

when the text is copiedinto the input i can't move it anymore unless another text is copied throught the button near the selection :

here is my jquery code :

```
if($('#rightoption:selected').val() === $("#chosen").val())
{
    $('#remove').attr('disabled' ,'disabled');
}
else ($('#right option:selected').val() !==$("#chosen").val())
{
    $('#remove').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

chosen is the id for the input.

but the problem is that when i select something different from the thing in the input he still disabled the button remove

Comment: post your html dom structure

Comment: You missed `if` in second condition.

Comment: Is that a accurate copy paste of your Javascript?

Comment: `else` takes no conditions. You mean `if(..){...}else if(..){...}`

Comment: "rightoption" then "right option" ?

Comment: `$('#remove').prop('disabled' , $('#right option:selected').val() === $("#chosen").val());`

Comment: @adeneo Shouldn't we close that as typo(s) ?

Comment: @dystroy - not sure, it is indeed a typo, but it's not really just a missing character, but a lack of understanding, so I think it deserves an answer, which you have given.

Comment: @dystroy - and maybe note that just changing the attribute can lead to strange results, and the OP really should be using `prop` to change the `disabled` property.

Comment: how can i  use .prop ? because with your exemple it blocked the entire selection  i can't touch it is it normal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This :

```
else ($('#right option:selected').val() !==$("#chosen").val())
{
    $('#remove').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

is equivalent to

```
else {
    $('#right option:selected').val() !==$("#chosen").val(); // this does nothing
}
$('#remove').removeAttr('disabled');
```

You probably wanted

```
if($('#right option:selected').val() === $("#chosen").val()){
    $('#remove').attr('disabled' ,'disabled');
} else {
    $('#remove').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

or better :

```
$('#remove').prop(
     'disabled', $('#right option:selected').val() === $("#chosen").val()
);
```

And I suppose the first test should have `'#right option:selected'` (note the space).

Comment: where is it different from what i have done ? the result is the same right ?

Comment: @Ynajar - It's rather well explained in the answer, yours is basically not doing at all what you think it is doing, and checking for something, then checking for the opposite in an else statement is superfluous, the else statement does exactly that anyway.

Comment: yes you're right but if i do the else without any condition and only the bracket's with the remove it won't work whereas i believe the condition are correct .

Comment: @Ynajar `else` isn't supposed to take conditions. `else` only runs if your `if` condition was false.